# React setState on a functionComponent doesn't re-render the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Help 'm having trouble re-rendering a page on a react function component. I want to fetch data on the initial load of a page, that's why I use an uuid that is fed to the page as a props and initiated it as an empty string when the page loaded for the first time. But setting the uuid or attachment a new value doesn't re-render the page. What did I do wrong here?

```
  const [attachments, setAttachments] = React.useState<IAttachment[]>([]);
  const [uuid, setUuid] = React.useState('');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (uuid !== props.uuid) {
      const fetchAttachment = async () => {
        const accessToken: string = AuthHelper.GetAccessToken() || '';
        if (accessToken) {
          if (activeItem.AttachmentFolderId !== undefined) {
            const attachments: IAttachment[] = await GraphService.getAttachments(accessToken, activeItem.CreatorId, activeItem.AttachmentFolderId);
            setAttachments([...attachments]);
            
          }
        }
      }
      fetchAttachment();
      setUuid(props.uuid);
      console.log('State updated');
    }
  }, []);
```

attachments is used as a props for a list component.

Comment: You need to add the `props.uuid` to the dependency array of `useEffect`. Right now inner function is called only on the first render. You don't really need this `uuid` state (if it is the only place you are using it).

Comment: What is `activeItem`? Are you sure that `setAttachments` will be called? Putting `uuid` on render function (just for test purpose) does not reload page?

Comment: @Saris, thanks your comment does solve the problem.
activeItem is a state, setAttachment did get called on every render.